# In postgresql, copy a view from one database on remote server to a table on local server

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy, postgresql-14

I have a remote postgresql server running with views in one of the schema. I need to copy the data from a view in the remote database server and put it in a new table in my local database server

**Assume**

***remote***

remote host: hostA

remote port: 5432

remote db: dbA

remote schema: schemaA

remote user: userA

remote password: passA

***local***

local host: hostB

local port: 5432

local db: dbB

local schema: schemaB

local user: userB

local password: passB

Comment: Hi - as views don’t contain data, do you mean copy the tables that the view uses or create a brand new table in the target that contains the data that the view displays?

Comment: Yes, I need to take the data the view is showing and create a new table in my local database and put it there

Comment: from hostB you can access the data of hostA as a foreign table, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)

Comment: Besides using [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) and using a remote connection per @Edouard comment you could just dump the underlying tables using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html): `pg_dump -h <some_host> -U <user> -d <the_db> -t <the table>` . You can repeat `-t` to get multiple tables. If the tables already exist on the other database then add `-a` to get only the data.